# Keep activities running after power button was pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm starting activity with startActivityForResult and then press power button. Activity is stopped and onActivityResult is triggered only after waking the screen on. Tried to acquire WakeLock before launching that activity to allow running it on background and retrieving activity result, but activity is still stopped after screen lock and doesn't finishes.

What I want is having activity finished after screen lock and deliver it's result to the previous one. Here's the code I use:

```
ActivityUtils.acquireWakeLock(Constants.TAG_NEXT);
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityUtils.getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
ActivityUtils.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, NEXT_RESULT);
```

And after NextActivity is finished I'd like to get results here:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PlayerControl.NEXT_RESULT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // do stuff
        }
        ActivityUtils.releaseWakeLock(Constants.TAG_NEXT);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an AsyncTask instead of a second Activity.

Comment: Don't want to break that code architecture right now. But yes, you're right.